# How to handle Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

InboxFragment is a fragment of MainActivity. 
In action bar menu of the MainActivity (those three dots on the ActionBar), I added an option Refresh Inbox, which calls a function retrieveMessages() by creating an object of InboxFragment.
retrieveMessages is a 'member' function in InboxFragment (which was earlier in onCreateView function of the fragment to retrieve messages, then I refactored it to extract code to reuse it in MainActivity).

I have tried using intent to re-create MainActivity by using this, MainActivity.class as parameters of the Intent but that is kind of an ugly refresh. How to handle the above error?

Here are the required pieces of code:
In MainActivity:

```
 @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int itemId = item.getItemId();

switch(itemId) {

//pieces of code we're not concerned with

    case R.id.action_refresh_inbox:
    InboxFragment inboxFragment = new InboxFragment();
    inboxFragment.retrieveMessages();
    break;
    }
}
```

In InboxFragment.java -

```
public class InboxFragment extends ListFragment {
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_inbox, container, false);

            return rootView;
    }
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        retrieveMessages();
    }

    public void retrieveMessages() {
//code that was earlier running in onResume(){};
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
01-11 01:35:44.515  21968-21968/com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
01-11 01:35:44.535  21968-22032/com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat D/mali_winsys﹕ new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [227x88]-format:1
01-11 01:35:44.945  21968-21968/com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-11 01:35:44.945  21968-21968/com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat, PID: 21968
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:328)
            at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:222)
            at com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.UI.InboxFragment$1.done(InboxFragment.java:67)
            at com.ghostriley.sgt.ghostchat.UI.InboxFragment$1.done(InboxFragment.java:55)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:115)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Is there any way to cal InboxFragment.onResume() ?

Comment: Post some essential parts of your code in Activity and Fragment here by editing the question.

Comment: I was just adding...added all the required methods that (the changes I made since the app started crashing), and logcat. Thanks

Comment: You're making new instance of `InboxFragment` in the refresh method, by doing `new InboxFragment();` This fragment is never added to your activity. So instead of making new instance every time, save the first time created fragment reference in a class-level variable and call the refresh method on that instance.

Comment: Try putting retrieveMessages() before return rootView;

Answer (score 0):

You haven't attached your `Fragment` to your `Activity`. You'll need something along the lines of:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, inboxFragment)
    .commit();
```